# What is the pulverize Exp Bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

I saw it flash once, and I didn't have time to read its description...

So what exactly is the Pulverize Exp bonus, and what could be the strategies to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Also new in Diablo 3 is the "Pulverize" experience bonus. This bonus xp is granted for successfully springing a trap or otherwise using your environment to deal damage to a foe."

This comes from experience as well as : [HERE](http://ezinearticles.com/?An-Overview-Of-Experience-In-Diablo-3&id=6853368)

Answer (score 0):

The Pulverized bonus is given for killing enemies with elements of the dungeon, such as the chandeliers, broken walls, and rolling log traps.