# How do I catch enemies in environment traps?

Tags: diablo-iii

I know that there is a [Pulverized bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68326/what-is-the-pulverize-exp-bonus) for damaging enemies in environmental traps.  I found many references to the fact ***that*** the bonus exists - including answers to the referenced question, but I can't seem to find any suggestions on how to actually trigger traps and catch enemies in them.  I've played the game for a while and I've still yet to catch a single enemy in a trap.  Is there a good strategy for catching enemies in traps?  Are some traps just really hard to use or totally luck based?  I'm taking it in the teeth a fair bit from the enemy, and I want to dish out some reciprocal pain!

Comment: Environments do more damage in higher difficulties. Just thought I'd mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enemies tend to stand around in the line of fire for traps in many cases, especially in the early going. The issue is more one of triggering them while they're nearby.  For instance, in the Cathedral there are many, many, many chandeliers.  Typically there will be "zombie type" enemies feasting on a corpse directly underneath.  The trick to these tends to be just getting to the chandelier chain and activating it without disturbing the zombies.  In some cases, it's not easy or worth it to trigger them - the enemies are between you and the chain, and you might as well kill them while you're headed in that direction.

Many of the other traps in the game are actually *destruction* rather than *interaction* based - so if you happen to be playing a barbarian or monk (with limited ranged skills at low levels), you may not have noticed the difference.  These traps are generally pretty easy to trigger before the enemies notice you, and they will severely injure or kill enemies, at least in Normal.  You can tell the difference in a class of traps by what your character does when you interact - if they swing their weapon, it's a destruction-based trap, and if they don't, it's interaction based.  Oak also points out that the color is different - interactive is blue, and destruction is red.

Unless you're farming trap kills, it's typically not worth the trouble to go and kite distant enemies into the trap kill zone - you can probably kill them faster than it would take to get them to follow you anyhow.

At higher difficulties, while the trap damage scales, it does not scale as fast as monster health does.  Therefore, getting "pulverized" bonuses is much harder, as is the related achievement.  If you're trying to farm this, I'd probably suggest running the Cathedral on Normal, with no followers or pets.

Comment: The color is also different - items you interact with are highlighted in blue, items you destroy are highlighted in red.

Comment: I've just gotten my first ranged attack as the barb, and I've noticed that while difficult, I can hit traps with it.  I'll keep trying.  The chandeliers seemed a good bet when I was in that zone, but I could rarely resist running into the fray as you mention.  Now the traps I see just tend to be hard to reach for melee, but maybe some ranged will do the trick.  I've had enough logs dropped on my handsome face.  I want payback.

Comment: @EBongo, note also that traps you can trigger don't do damage to you or allies, so don't be shy about running up to them and bashing them in close quarters.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of different ones: the chandeliers which require you to activate the chain to drop them - you can see them floating above where they'd hit. The broken sections of wall, which crumble when hit and damage any enemies in front of them. Rolling log traps which work similarly.. so on and so forth. It can definitely be tough to line up a substantial amount of enemies where they can get killed by the traps, but that's part of the fun.

Just keep an eye on the environment and watch for things that fall, explode, or crash.